# How to catch exceptions in SendMailAsync method

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, email

I have a C# wcf Windows service in .net 4.5 that sends emails to about 1000 different  customers daily. I would like to try sending the emails async using this snippet of code I found here on SO, but how should I wrap it to catch exceptions?

```
public async Task SendAsync(string subject, string body, string recipient)
{
    var mailMessage = new MailMessage("me@example.com", recipient, subject, body);
    mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;

    using(var client = new SmtpClient("mysmtpserver"))
    {
        try
        {
            await client.SendMailAsync(mailMessage);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           // Log here
        }
    }
}
```

I'm expecting exceptions from invalid e-mail adresses and server timeouts.

Should I just wrap the await Call in a try-catch? Not sure this will work.

Also where is the best place to put the foreach loop that runs through all mail adresses?

Thanks.

Comment: Timeouts are inevitable, but invalid e-mails should be checked prior to sending the mail. Don't rely on exceptions for normal execution flow.

Comment: Depends on the control flow you want. Do you want it to terminate on the first failure?

Comment: Should pref just log the exception and go on to the next recipient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Should I just wrap the await Call in a try-catch? Not sure this will work.

Yes, `await` propagates exceptions and this will work. Of course, many mail delivery failures occur after the mail has left your servers and you get a bounce back or even nothing. This is not detectable no matter how you send the mail.

> Also where is the best place to put the foreach loop that runs through all mail addresses?

Not sure what you mean. Place the loop around a call to `SendAsync`? Where else could it go? I probably misunderstand.

Comment: Thanks. What I meant was if I could send an array of recipients and simply reuse the smtp client inside the method.

Comment: You can do that but I think the client could become "hosed" when it looses its connection or something.

Answer (score 1):

I know that this is a old post and it is answered already but I am able to catch `await` calls using this method.

```js
public async Task < JsonResult > UserDelete(string username) {
  // return obj
  MFFCommon retval = new MFFCommon();

  // get user
  var user = UserManager.FindByName(username);
  
  // starts a task
  Task removeUserFromAgency = await Task.Factory.StartNew(async() => {
    await removeUserFromCurrentAgency(user);
  });
  
  // optional, but this will wait 3 sec before checking if it is complete.
  removeUserFromAgency.Wait(3000);
  
  
  if (removeUserFromAgency.IsCompleted) {
    retval.taskResponse = "True";
    retval.taskError = null;
    return Json(retval, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
  } else {
    // This is where the exception is at.
    retval.taskResponse = "False";
    retval.taskError = removeUserFromAgency.Exception.Message;
    return Json(retval, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
  }
}
```